# Fill DataGridView on FbRemoteEvent

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, firebird

I have one MainForm (with dataGridView) and DataModule class with my own LoadDataTable method which execute FbCommand select sql and fill datatable in dataset and FbRemoteEvent catch method. When I run my app, in MainForm_OnLoad I call LoadDataTable method and my dataGridView show data successfully. But when my app catch FbRemoteEvent from server and call LoadDataTable method, exception occurred in dataGridView. Why?

**MainForm:**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    private readonly DataModule _dataModule = DataModule.GetInstance();

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = _dataModule.AppDataSet;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "MESSAGEQUEUE";
        _dataModule.LoadMessageQueueDataTable();
    }
}
```

**DataModule:**

```
    private void FirebirdRemoteEventOnRemoteEventCounts(object sender, FbRemoteEventEventArgs fbRemoteEventEventArgs)
        {
            switch (fbRemoteEventEventArgs.Name.Trim().ToUpper())
            {
                case "QUEUE_NEW_MESSAGE":
                    if (fbRemoteEventEventArgs.Counts > 0)
                    {
                        LoadMessageQueueDataTable();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }

public void LoadMessageQueueDataTable()
        {
            if (ConnectToFirebird())
            {
                using (var firebirdTransaction = FirebirdConnection.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    using (var firebirdCommand = new FbCommand
                    {
                        Connection = firebirdTransaction.Connection,
                        Transaction = firebirdTransaction,
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                        CommandText = "select MESSAGEQUEUEID, CREATEDATETIME, SENDER, RECIPIENT, TEXT from MESSAGEQUEUE"
                    })
                    {
                        AppDataSet.Tables["MESSAGEQUEUE"].Clear();
                        try
                        {
                            AppDataSet.Tables["MESSAGEQUEUE"].Load(firebirdCommand.ExecuteReader());
                            firebirdCommand.Transaction.Commit();
                        }
                        catch (FbException firebirdException)
                        {
                            firebirdCommand.Transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Error:**
[image]

Comment: Could you display the english error message instead. Also are you populating the dataset on the event thread or on a different thread?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Exception in DataGridView:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index 0 is not set.
in System.Windows.Forms.CurrencyManager.get_Item(Int32 index)
in System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataGridViewDataConnection.GetError(Int32 rowIndex)

To replace this default window handle the event DataError.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't create another thread to load datatable when catch FbRemoteEvent

Comment: As far as I am aware Firebird events are handled on a different thread (not 100% sure though)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel If we update data direct in visual component, we can use delegate i think. But dataset isn't visual component and don't have InvokeRequired property... The strangest thing that a similar program in successful work, but I can not find the differences between projects in this part.

Comment: Yes, now check, FbEvents are handled in other thread. What else can try to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DataModule class add and change FbRemoteEvent handler:

```
public delegate void DelegateMessageQueueTableUpdate();
public event DelegateMessageQueueTableUpdate MessageQueueTableUpdate;

private void FirebirdRemoteEventOnRemoteEventCounts(object sender, FbRemoteEventEventArgs fbRemoteEventEventArgs)
        {
            switch (fbRemoteEventEventArgs.Name.Trim().ToUpper())
            {
                case "QUEUE_NEW_MESSAGE":
                    if (fbRemoteEventEventArgs.Counts > 0)
                    {
                        if (MessageQueueTableUpdate != null)
                        {
                            MessageQueueTableUpdate();
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

In MainForm:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private readonly DataModule _dataModule = DataModule.GetInstance();

        private delegate void RefreshMessageQueueTable();

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _dataModule.MessageQueueTableUpdate += () =>
            {
                if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    dataGridView1.Invoke(new RefreshMessageQueueTable(_dataModule.LoadMessageQueueDataTable));
                }
                else
                {
                    _dataModule.LoadMessageQueueDataTable();
                }
            };
        }

        private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _dataModule.AppDataSet;
            dataGridView1.DataMember = "MESSAGEQUEUE";
            _dataModule.LoadMessageQueueDataTable();
        }
    }
```